# Implementing I2C slave with FT201XB via USB

Tags: arduino, usb, i2c, ftdi

I've been trying to test a FT201XQ USB-I2C breakout board: UMFT201XB-01, so I can connect it to a master device such as an Arduino and sniff what that device is sending through I2C.

To see the output of the slave device I have successfully configured a Virtual COM PORT by installing the D2XX drivers provided by ftdchip.com. I can open the serial port through puTTY and everything seems fine in that regard.

Then, i've loaded the "master_writer" example on my Arduino, which sends 1 byte at a time to an address (0x22 is specified in the UM201XB-01 datasheet as the default address).

Nothing seems to happen in the COM port that i've earlier opened. Do I need to configure/program the FTDI device in some way? In that case, how can I do it, in a general way?

UMFT201XB-01 board http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_UMFT201_220_230XB.pdf

Thank you in advance, and sorry if this is a "noob" question : P

Comment: I2C is a *synchronous* serial mode, while the Virtual Com Port traditionally only works in *asynchronous* mode.  You probably need a different driver or API to use that USB device with a synchronous mode, so it's unsurprising that you would see nothing in a terminal program.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I figured it might be related to the nature of both types of communication, but the only drivers available are those present in the ftdichip website. 

I'll be using arduino as a slave device from now on and use my main development board (ARM7 based) as master, it's much easier to implement and it suffices for now. Maybe later i'll try some sort of sniffer to see if the original I2C slave was receiving data or not.